# Передать jQuery ширину рабочей области окна в переменную PHP чтобы сравнить значения

Tags: php, jquery

Как мне записать `$(window).width()` в GET переменную PHP чтобы сравнить данные

```
<?php
    // условие: если рабочая область окна меньше 800px
    if ($_GET['window_width'] < 800)
    {
        echo 'Недостаточно рабочей области окна';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Отлично. Я могу вывести вам весь контент';
    }
```

Comment: Что-то вы не то хотите сделать.

Comment: @Visman а как правильно проверить, если требуется показать тот или иной контент исходя из ширины окна?

Comment: Адаптивный дизайн почему вас не устраивает? Медиа-запросы в css для изменения дизайна?

Comment: @Visman к сожалению, некуда больше адаптировать, там блок который нельзя сжать, можно только убрать с него несколько элементов. Я и планирую это сделать исходя из размеров окна.

Comment: а если окно браузера потом увеличить? что будет по вашему? блок это таблица? сверстать таблицу подругому? добавить в конце концов скролл горизонтальный?

Comment: Блоки скрывать от вывода на экран тоже можно через медиа запросы. В этом нет проблемы.

Comment: @xaja не планируется что окно будет увеличиваться, предполагается что посетители будут иметь разную ширину экрана: смартфон, монитор 15, монитор 17, планшет еще что-то. Блок - таблица.

Comment: Крутил это передачей параметра через $.get() при загрузке страницы, но к результату не пришел.

Comment: А нельзя вот этот самый `800px` хранить как постоянную величину на самой странице в виде переменной JS? И сравнивать значения `window_width` именно с этой JS переменной, а не отправлять каждый раз проверяемое значение на сервер.

Comment: @StasHappy тогда можно скрыть некоторые div элементы проверяя ширину внутри скрипта. Из-за незнания я предполагал, что можно передать значение в переменную php. таким образом не загружая на страницу лишний html код.

Comment: @Plush, давай те по порядку. Пользователь заходит на Вашу страницу. Что должен делать JS в этот момент? Он должен проверять размер окна браузера и подстраивать некоторые элементы страницы исходя из этого размера?

Comment: @StasHappy если размер рабочей области окна меньше 800px - показываем `<div>div1  div2  div5</div>` если больше, то `<div>div1  div2  div3  div4  div5  div6</div>`

Comment: В таком случае, можно в `css` сразу скрыть некоторые `div` блоки и показывать их только в случае, если ширина больше чем 800px. Это можно сделать без использования проверок на сервере, только лишь используя JS. Но Вас это не устраивает как я полагаю?

Comment: @StasHappy этому я научился; примерно, будет так `if ($(window).width() < 800) { $("#div1, #div3, #div5").hide(); }` то что мне нужно, правда я думал что можно уменьшить вес страницы за счет сравнения внутри PHP.

Comment: @Plush, `if ($(window).width() < 800) { $("#div1, #div3, #div5").hide(); }` вот это все легко делается через css. Читайте про медиа запросы.

Comment: @Visman http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media оно?

Comment: @Plush, оно + запрос в гугле https://www.google.com/search?q=%40media+css&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8